# svn update slow (15+ minutes on a 1Mb repository)

Tags: svn

Running `svn update` on our live server sometimes takes more than 15 minutes to complete.

1. Our repository is very small, around 1Mb with ~100 files (it's a small website)
2. We have a couple of developers that do both commit/update and this is working very good
3. We update all changes on our server (which only does `svn update`) and this is running painfully slow
4. We have never done a `svn commit` from the server (it's supposed to be a read-only version of our site)

As time goes by it seems to get slower and slower to do `svn update` on the server, even if it's just one file that needs to be updated. I'm starting to think that the "age" of the repository on our server has to do with how slow it is? If so, is there anything we can do to speed it up?

UPDATE #1

I still think the "age" has something to do with `svn update` being slow, but might have to consider what is actually happening when the repository "age" on the server...

The reason I think this is the following:

1. We have checked out the repository on WebsiteA (using `svn checkout`) and updated it on regular intervals (using `svn update`) since January 2010
2. We have also checked out the same repository on WebsiteZ the same way, but this happened just a few days ago ie July 2012
3. Both WebsiteA and WebsiteZ are on the same physical server and both are using the same repository
4. Running `svn update` on WebsiteA to update from revision 100 to 101 takes 20+ minutes
5. Running `svn update` on WebsiteZ to update from revision 100 to 101 takes just a few seconds

The only difference between these websites that I can see is that WebsiteA has existed a bit longer. WebsiteA may have a few extra files in it (cached content), though this is very minimal (less than 20 files) and the directories that contain the cache files have been set to ignore all files using svn:ignore.

I guess I couldn't rule out network issues, but I assume that WebsiteA and WebsiteZ would run the same firewall settings and if there was a rule it would be a "block" rather than "delay". Since both websites are on the same server I assume they should both update in the same amount of time in terms of network issues.

UPDATE #2

It might be worth noting that if we do `svn update file.txt` it runs very fast. It's as if svn is comparing everything we have in the directory, just to figure out what to update.

UPDATE #3

We ended up upgrading svn and upgrading all checked out revisions. `svn update` seems to run a lot faster now and fingers crossed it stays that way. Thank you everyone for helping!!

UPDATE #4

Sure, doing a fresh checkout solved the problem, but only for a few days/weeks. I think finally today we found the cause of svn being slow. We're using Zend_Auth and call Zend_Auth::hasIdentity() on every page to check if users are logged in. This call creates a session, which in turn creates a session file on the server. If the browser (or googlebot) is browsing with cookies turned off we create one session file for every single request. Hence our session directory had millions of files. We deleted the files in the directory and fixed the way we determine if the user is logged in by checking if the cookie has been set before calling hasIdentity(). `svn` updates now run at <30 seconds.

Comment: What protocol are you using?  I have encountered some case before that, someone setup a svn repo on a network drive, and people used file:// protocol to access, the performance is horrible.  Once I helped to startup an svnserve and people used svn:// protocol, everything become reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. We're using svn://

Comment: it seems to me that it is something between your "server" and your svn repo causing the problem, coz I just found that you said developers are doing svn update without problem.  If the slowness is caused by the svn repo, your developers will suffer too but it is not the case.

Comment: I thought that could be the case too (and it might be) but we've got similar repositories with other websites that are using the same svn repository and those are updating fast. The only difference is the "age" of the repositories. Ie the repositories that update fast are rather new (a couple of weeks), and the ones that are slow are old (1-2 years).

Comment: you could try an "svn cleanup" on websiteA.
since other working copies work well I think it is not the server.
It may be the client used (habe websiteA and websiteB a different client? or was a different version used before and some conversion is taking place?)
I would also try to make a fresh new checkout for websiteA just for testing.
Is the size of the .svn folders very different for both websiteA and B?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The .svn folders on websiteA and B are both the exact same size. We did a `svn cleanup` but it seems the updates are still taking 15+ minutes. We have however updated the svn repository during the time websiteA has been around. This might be the case. We'll have to do that fresh checkout and that will probably solve it (wish there was an easier solution though :)).

Comment: @user1493124 Did you take a look at any logs?  A little inspection, possibly turning up the logging level, with an eye to processing times, can go a long way.  In any event, post them with "sensitive items" replaced by dummy information, so this doesn't just become one huge guessing game.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I have two servers where my site exists.  One of the two servers where the website is located _also_ has the SVN repository.  On _that_ server the svn udpate runs really slow but on the _remote_ server it runs lightning fast..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reconstructing the subversion repository (after backing it up!) by using `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`, eg as described in the [manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate). It could be that there are some anomalies in the repository caused when upgrading through old versions.  You say that this is an old repository, so this could be the case here. Doing a dump -> load cycle means that Subversion may create a more optimal repository in the current format.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This could definitely be the case. We've upgraded the SVN server 2-3 times and also moved servers since we checked out the first version of the site. Will give your suggestions a go and let you know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SVN writes the source files and equal amount of meta data (.svn directory) into local disk. If network is not the issue, you could also check how the disk performance is. I have come across situations, where the SAN disk was slow (network delay, error checking between local and remote data and so on) and it was causing SVN delay. Usually in that case, a local disk should work better. You could try the following things:

- If possible do `svn export` on to the same server as the repository and svn daemon is running. If it runs faster there, then it is either network or disk.
- If `svn export` on other client/dev machines runs faster, then it should be the disk.

I doubt if age of repository has anything to do with performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I did the tests you suggested and don't think I can rule anything out. I've updated the original question with more details regarding what is happening. I hope this explains it more. I really appreciate your feedback and for taking the time to help us out!